# Separate ATmega 2560 - turn on a single LED - troubleshooting

Tags: programming, led, uploading, sketch

I have got my own PCB with "some stuff" on it and first I want to make it run a simple "turn on LED".

My setup:

- Atmega 2560
- LED connected to PE4 (D2 in Arduino language) => PE4 - LED - 1K resistor - 5V
- ceramic resonator (CSTCE16M0V53-R0 16MHZ) connected to XTAL1 + XTAL2 with 1MOhm resistor in between
- all VINs are pulled to GND with capacitors

[image: resonator VINs GNDs]
[image: RESET circuit]
[image: status LEDs]

Upload is working through ICSP (MISO, MOSI, SCK, RESET, 5V, GND) with an USBasp

Here is my **Arduino sketch**, which I upload through the Arduino software:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);    
}
```

I checked the fuses on the Atmega as well:

```
avrdude: safemode: lfuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as D8
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FD
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:FD, E:D8, L:FF)
```

avrdude uploads successfully: *(output truncated!)*

```
avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801
avrdude: NOTE: "flash" memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: writing flash (1518 bytes):
Writing | ################################################## | 100% 5.47s
avrdude: 1518 bytes of flash written
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 3.45s
avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1518 bytes of flash verified

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Problem: the LED doesn't work. It is OFF all the time.

Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: You have forgotten to mention what the problem even is.

Comment: You're right. I edited my post. The LED isnt blinking.

Comment: Have you tested the voltage at the pin?

Comment: When you say it doesn't blink, can you clarify: Is it on all the time, or off all the time?

Comment: it is off all the time. @NickGammon

// which pin do you mean

Comment: At the pin that's supposed to be blinking.

Comment: Try pin D52 (the SCK pin) since we know that works or you wouldn't have been able to upload the sketch in the first place.

Comment: Everything on the PCB is already hard wired and I cannot change. I can try to pull a temporary cable from D52 to the LED. I will give it a try // I will also test the LED itself (just apply 5V) and I will measure the voltage when I remove blinking and just turn the LED on. Will come back later!

Comment: Well, you should have access to the SCK pin, because you use that to program the thing. It's what you plug the ICSP cable into.

Comment: I updated the original question: I need to pull the output pin to LOW to make the LED work ( PE4 - LED - 1K resistor - 5V). When I put a cable between PE4 and GND the LED works. I have no LED attached to SCK but I can attach one to the ICSP header where I have connection to the SCK pin. Good idea! @NickGammon

Comment: You haven't mentioned any capacitors - any of the *required* decoupling capacitors on the power pins, the *critical* capacitors on the crystal, etc.  Also you haven't mentioned what your reset circuitry is like - are you pulling the RESET pin HIGH through a resistor?  **Show your full circuit**

Comment: I mentioned the capacitors of the power pins in my original question. They are all conected to GND with a 100nF cap. The crystal has got internal caps and RESET is pulled to HIGH with a 10K resistor. @Majenko

Comment: @jblaze That's not a crystal, that's a ceramic resonator - a very different beast.

Comment: @Majenko OK sorry, you are right. This comes straight from the Arduino2560 reference design.

Comment: @Majenko I added the relevant circuits to the original question

Comment: @jblaze Do you have an oscilloscope?  Can you see if the resonator is oscillating at 16MHz?  (Tip: set the probe to 10x)

Comment: @Majenko sorry I don't have an oscilloscope

Comment: @jblaze Then you really should see about acquiring one - even a dirt cheap ancient analog one from eBay that you can get for next to nothing.  They are an *essential* piece of equipment for circuit diagnostics.

Comment: @Majenko Thanks for the hint. When there is a problem with the crystal/ceramic resonator, would I have been able to program the Atmega?

Comment: @jblaze Quite probably yes - I can't remember the details on the Atmel chips, but either it uses the incoming SCK as the system clock, or it switches to the internal 1MHz RC clock, I forget which - it allows you to set the fuses regardless of what the rest of the circuit is doing.

Comment: `I need to pull the output pin to LOW to make the LED work` - I see. But it doesn't blink? It won't with your altered sketch.

Comment: @NickGammon I only want it to turn on for the first shot.

Comment: I'm losing track of your problem. The way you wired it, as far as I can tell, you *expect* it to turn on if you digitalWrite LOW to it. You initially said it didn't blink, and then you said `I need to pull the output pin to LOW to make the LED work` - so working as expected. What are you expecting exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying that the LED lights if you write LOW to it.

> I need to pull the output pin to LOW to make the LED work

That's exactly what you expect.

[image: LED wiring]

Since the other end of the LED is wired to +5 V, then you need to drive the pin low to have a voltage difference over the LED, and for it to light.

---

> I double checked the Atmega and it is a ATmega2560V, which is rated for 8Mhz. Any chance to fix this with the existing PCB? Change the Fuses to use the internal clock?

Yes, I suggest you do that.

Look at [Engbedded Atmel AVR® Fuse Calculator](http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc) to see what to set them to. I suggest the internal 8 MHz oscillator.

Comment: Yes, I have to pull it LOW but nothing happens.

Comment: Well it shouldn't take long to change the sketch to refer to pin 52 (SCK), upload that, jumper your LED to the SCK pin, and test.

Comment: Unfortunatly this doesn't work :-(

Comment: Please measure the pin with a multimeter. Upload your earlier "blink" sketch. See whether or not the pin changes voltage.

Comment: The pin set to LOW and measured against GND, the resistance is infinite. When I set the pin to high the voltage swings between 5-8mV.

Comment: Can you post a photo of you measuring that pin? I can't believe that you can upload new code, but the SCK pin is incapable of behaving like a normal pin.

Comment: Here it is: [measure1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mttin6g10dmr9eu/Foto%2014.07.15%2007%2010%2053.jpg?dl=0) and [measure2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bnd4wv896pfi3m/Foto%2014.07.15%2007%2011%2027.jpg?dl=0) - I disconnected SCK and 5V and measured between both pins

Comment: Normally voltages are measured with reference to GND. So what I expect you to do is run the sketch, and while the board is powered measure between the SCK pin and the GND plane.

Comment: OK, let me describe in detail: first I set SCK to HIGH and measured against GND: 5-8mV. Afterwards set SCK to LOW and measured against 5V: 0V.

Comment: I double checked the Atmega and it is a ATmega2560V, which is rated for 8Mhz. Any chance to fix this with the existing PCB? Change the Fuses to use the internal clock?

Comment: See amended answer.

Comment: OK thanks. Are these appropriate fuses to go for? "-U lfuse:w:0xc2:m -U hfuse:w:0x99:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m"

Comment: it is working!! Thanks to all participants!